# Javascript newbie : Array.isArray() query

Tags: javascript

I have been reading that in Javascript :

- **Everything** is an object (except primitives such as number,string, boolean, null & undefined)
- Objects can be treated as associative **arrays**.

From what I conclude, Array.isArray() should return true for everything (with primitive exceptions aforementioned). What wrong did I understand ?

Thanks !

Comment: “Objects can be treated as associative arrays” does not mean “Objects are associative arrays”.

Comment: _"Objects can be treated as associative arrays"_ depending on just how you want to define "associative array". There is an obvious similarity, but "associative arrays" in some languages have certain characteristics that JS objects don't have (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between an Object and an Array. An **Array** is actually an Array **Object**. It has different methods than other objects. A String is a String **object**. However, you can access objects as if they were an array. Take the following object

```
var obj = {
    value1: 'Some Value',
    value2: 'Some Other Value'
    };
```

You can get values like

```
obj['value1'];
obj['value2'];
```

This doesn't mean that it's an **Array Object**, it just has a different way of accessing it

isArray() checks if the object is an **Array Object**, not if you can access it **like** an array

Answer (score 1):

Array (a [[Class]]-type in javascript) is not the same as Associative Array (abstract data type), `Array.isArray` checks if the object is a normal array, as in `({}).toString.call( obj ) === "[object Array]"`.

> 1. If Type(arg) is not Object, return false.
> 2. If the value of the [[Class]] internal property of arg is "Array", then return true.
> 3. Return false.